# Which database for a web application with similar requirements like file sharing/storage services?

Tags: database-design, query-performance

I am currently working on a web application that allows manufacturers to upload files (technical drawings of products), which they can then share with suppliers so that they can produce the corresponding parts.

As of now, I use the database to store user/company account related information. Furthermore, whenever a file is uploaded a reference, in which AWS bucket the file is stored, is saved in the database (in other words, I use the database to query from where to retrieve requested information). Due to the nature of the application much more requests will made to read data than to write it.

Not knowing much about database I started to build the back-end of my web app using a no-sql (mongoDB) database. As I am expanding the functionality of the back-end I am introducing a great deal of dependencies and therefore queries. Which data can be accessed depends on which company a user belongs to and the relation of that company to other companies, etc. Hence introducing all these queries will probably slow down my application significantly as the user base scales - please correct me if I am wrong.

Hence I want to ask which database you would recommend using for such an application?

Thank you in advance!

Best regards, Samuel

Comment: keep files out of the database as you've done. A few queries like you've suggested can be done anywhere with a speed that doesn't degrade your website experience. Keep with what you're familar with and grow your knowledge there.

Comment: @danblack wouldn't that querying a no sql database become slow once it contains multiple thousand documents? - I am hoping that many people will use the web app. Also switching at this point wouldn't be too much work and I don't really know any database well at this point... So theoretically speaking would a sql or mysql db be better suited? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Filesystems, document stores, and SQL implementations are designed around concurrent access. databases storing documents are additional processing overhead in accessing the files. So because you have that overhead you need to be sure you are getting an advantage by having them in the document store (backups, simplicity in replication). For looking up filenames, any database is fine. For documents, use one that has a document store. Choose the product that makes it easy to write your queries.

Comment: @danblack thank you very much for explaining this to me - I'll stick to my mongoDB then...